# Should there be some obligatory tags on questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

By seeing how meta works and by the specificity of the CR.SE, I think that could be a good fit.

On metas, questions have to be tag with at least one of [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) or [support](/questions/tagged/support). And that is pretty nice because it gives you an idea of what are the topics. It also make you able to find similar questions with ease as you can browse by these types, and all the question are under these types.

Reviewing always gets down to some specific aspects like [tag:refactoring, [optimization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization), [clean-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean-code), [best-practice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practice) or [security](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security). I think that any question is always about at least one of these tag (maybe I'm missing some, but you get the principle). We could probably get down to a list of 6 tags or something like that.

It think that having something similar could be very nice and help "experts" finding the question that they love the most, and for questions to find their experts!

It would also be helping new user who get on the site, as they would see the "global categories" of reviewing. When you are new on a SE it's sometimes hard to see what tag you should use (because of a lack of knowledge of existing tags).

Comment: What's the use case for these tags? Do people really want to look at all the clean-code questions?

Comment: Well personally, I always check for whether refactoring/clean-code/best practice question and never for security/optimization or whatever else.  And when question about these aren't tag properly I have a hard time to find them.

Comment: I think this might be worth trying just to filter out some of the misplaced non-working code questions that belong on SO. Maybe, just maybe, when people see that none of those tags fit their question, they will realize it's off-topic and go away, rather than just arbitrarily selecting one.

Answer (score 6):

[refactoring](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refactoring), [optimization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization), [clean-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean-code), [best-practice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practice) and [security](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) are more or less all *meta-tags*. By now, most of them have even been cleaned up already. (Which is not a big surprise as this question is two years old).

There is one and only one tag that is **required** on each and every question on Code Review: The language the code is in.